# Dart Testing with Riverpod StateNotifierProvider and AsyncValue as state

Tags: unit-testing, dart, asynchronous, riverpod, dart-test

This is my first app with Dart/Flutter/Riverpod, so any advice or comment about the code is welcome.

I'm using [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) as embedded db so the initial value for the provider's state is loaded asynchronously and using an [AsyncValue](https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/AsyncValue-class.html) of [riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod) to wrapped it.

The following code works but I've got some doubts about the testing approach, so I would like to confirm if I'm using the Riverpod lib as It supposed to be used.

This is my provider with its deps (`Preferences` is a HiveObject to store app general config data):

```dart
final hiveProvider = FutureProvider<HiveInterface>((ref) async {
  return await App.setUp();
});

final prefBoxProvider = FutureProvider<Box<Preferences>>((ref) async {
  final HiveInterface hive = await ref.read(hiveProvider.future);
  return hive.openBox<Preferences>("preferences");
});

class PreferencesNotifier extends StateNotifier<AsyncValue<Preferences>> {
  late Box<Preferences> prefBox;

  PreferencesNotifier(Future<Box<Preferences>> prefBoxFuture): super(const AsyncValue.loading()) {
    prefBoxFuture.then((value) {
      prefBox = value;
      _loadCurrentPreferences();
    });
  }

  void _loadCurrentPreferences() {
    Preferences pref = prefBox.get(0) ?? Preferences();
    state = AsyncValue.data(pref);    
  }

  Future<void> save(Preferences prefs) async {    
    await prefBox.put(0, prefs);
    state = AsyncValue.data(prefs);
  }

  Preferences? get preferences {    
    return state.when(data: (value) => value,
    error: (_, __) => null,
    loading: () => null);
  }

}


final preferencesProvider = StateNotifierProvider<PreferencesNotifier, AsyncValue<Preferences>>((ref) {
  return PreferencesNotifier(ref.read(prefBoxProvider.future));
});
```

And the following is the test case, I'm mocking the Hive box provider (`prefBoxProvider`):

```dart
class Listener extends Mock {
  void call(dynamic previous, dynamic value);
}

Future<Box<Preferences>> prefBoxTesting() async {
  final hive = await App.setUp();
  Box<Preferences> box = await hive.openBox<Preferences>("testing_preferences");
  await box.clear();
  return box;
}

void main() {
  
  test('Preferences value changes', () async {

    final container = ProviderContainer(overrides: [
        prefBoxProvider.overrideWithValue(AsyncValue.data(await prefBoxTesting()))
    ],);
    addTearDown(() {
      container.dispose();
      Hive.deleteBoxFromDisk("testing_preferences");
    });
    final listener = Listener();

    container.listen<AsyncValue<Preferences>>(
      preferencesProvider,
      listener,
      fireImmediately: true,
    );
    verify(listener(null, const TypeMatcher<AsyncLoading>())).called(1);
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(listener);
    // Next line waits until we have a value for preferences attribute
    await container.read(preferencesProvider.notifier).stream.first;
    verify(listener(const TypeMatcher<AsyncLoading>(), const TypeMatcher<AsyncData>())).called(1);
    
    Preferences preferences = Preferences.from(container.read(preferencesProvider.notifier).preferences!);
    
    preferences.currentListName = 'Lista1';
    await container.read(preferencesProvider.notifier).save(preferences);
    
    verify(listener(const TypeMatcher<AsyncData>(), const TypeMatcher<AsyncData>())).called(1);
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(listener);
    final name = container.read(preferencesProvider.notifier).preferences!.currentListName;
    expect(name, equals('Lista1'));
   });

}
```

I've used as reference the [official docs](https://riverpod.dev/es/docs/cookbooks/testing/) about testing Riverpod and the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/issues/57) related with `AsyncValue`s

Well, I found some problems to verify that the listener is called with the proper values, I used the `TypeMatcher` just to verify that the state instance has got the proper type and I check ("manually") the value of the wrapped object's attribute if It's the expected one. Is there a better way to achieve this ?

Finally, I didn't find too many examples with `StateNotifier` and `AsyncValue` as state type, Is there a better approach to implement providers that are initialized with deferred data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't like too much my original approach so I created my own `Matcher` to compare wrapped values in `AsyncValue` instances:

```dart
class IsWrappedValueEquals extends Matcher {
  final dynamic value;

  IsWrappedValueEquals(this.value);

  @override
  bool matches(covariant AsyncValue actual, Map<dynamic, dynamic> matchState) => 
    equals(actual.value).matches(value, matchState);

  @override
  Description describe(Description description) => description.add('Is wrapped value equals');
}
```

In the test, the final part is a bit different:

```dart
    Preferences preferences = Preferences.from(container.read(preferencesProvider.notifier).preferences!);
    
    preferences.currentListName = 'Lista1';
    await container.read(preferencesProvider.notifier).save(preferences);

// the following line is the new one
    verify(listener(IsWrappedValueEquals(Preferences()), IsWrappedValueEquals(preferences))).called(1);
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(listener);
}
```

I prefer my custom `Matcher` to the original code, but I feel that there are too many custom code to test something, apparently, common.

If anyone can tell me a better solution for this case, It'd be great.